# Expected height of the highest tree in this random forest

Tags: probability, graph-theory, expected-value, uniform-distribution, random-graphs

Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose, $\Gamma$ is a graph, in which $X_1, … , X_n$ are the vertices and every edge is drawn between a vertex $X_i$ and the vertex, that is the closest to it in the Euclidean metric.

> $\Gamma$ is almost surely a forest (all its connected components are trees).

*Proof:*

Suppose $X_{i_1}, ... , X_{i_n}$ form a cycle with non-zero probability. It is not hard to see, that it almost surely had to be an oriented cycle before we "erased" orientation. That means, that we can assume without the loss of generality $X_{i_{k+1 (\mod n)}}$ is always the closest to $X_{i_k}$. Thus, The sequence $||X_{i_{k+1 (\mod n)}}-X_{i_{k (\mod n)}}||$ is almost surely monotonously decreasing. But it is at the same time periodic with period $n$. And here we get a contradiction.

> What is the expectation of the largest diameter of connected component of $\Gamma$?

If an exact value is not possible, then asymptotic will also be accepted as a valid answer.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Is it HW? Is it from a book?

Comment: @quasi, no it is not. I just accidentally came up with this question.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the case $m=1$?

Comment: @quasi, in case $m = 1$, we have that if we sort the vertices in ascending order as $X_{i_1}, ... , X_{i_n}$, then any connected component will be a "bamboo" formed by a maximal subsequences of the form $X_{i_k}, X_{i_{k+1}}, ... , X_{i_l}$, for which the sequence $(X_{i_{k+1}} - X_{i_k}), ... ,(X_{i_{l}} - X_{i_{l - 1}})$ will be monotonous. However, I failed to derive anything else from that...

Comment: Are the edges directed or undirected?

Comment: @quasi, we assume the edges to be undirected. Initially, the building process of them implies the edges being directed, but we "erase" this direction after our graph is built.

Comment: For $m > 1$, I doubt that you can do much better than a simulation. Have you tried setting up a simulation?

Comment: @quasi, suppose $X_{i_1}, ... , X_{i_n}$ form a cycle with non-zero probability. It is not hard to see, that it almost surely had to be an oriented cycle before we "erased" orientation. That means, that we can assume without the loss of generality $X_{i_{k+1 (\mod n)}}$ is always the closest to $X_{i_k}$. Thus, The sequence $||X_{i_{k+1 (\mod n)}}-X_{i_{k (\mod n)}}||$ is almost surely monotonously decreasing. But it is at the same time periodic with period $n$. And here we get a contradiction.

Comment: Assuming all distances are distinct, a cycle is impossible (consider the longest edge in a supposed cycle).

Comment: @quasi, that is exactly what I was talking about in my last comment.

Comment: If we let $e(m,n)$ denote the expected max path length, then $e(1,2)=1/3$ and $e(1,3)=1/2$. For $n\ge 2$ the values of $e(1,n)$ appear to be strictly decreasing for $n\ge 2$, approaching zero as a limit.

Comment: But I now think that except for very small values of $n$, finding an exact value for $e(m,n)$ won't be achievable, even for the case $m=1$. Just settle for a simulation..

Comment: I'm confused, if each vertex draws an edge to its nearest neighbor, wont you just end up with a bunch of disjoint pairs of neighbors?  Edit: nevermind that was silly.

Comment: @JakeMirra, consider $m = 1$, $n = 3$, $X_1 = 0$, $X_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, $X_3 = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: In any case, your thoughts about the problem merit an upvote.